# Active Directory - Add multiple groups with a split and foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I am working with AD groups (member of tab). I have the following code:

```
$VPNGroups = $Line.'Business Partner Employee - AD Group Membership'
$VPNGroup = $VPNGroups -split ';'

foreach ($ADGroup in $VPNGroup) {
        if ($ADGroup -ne "") {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $SamAccountName -MemberOf $ADGroup -WarningVariable 'VPNGroupError';trap{continue}}
        if (-not $VPNGroupError) {
            $LogFile.WriteLine("AddToVPN" + "," + $SamAccountName + "," + $GivenName + "," + $Sn + "," + $ADGroup)
            Write-Verbose ($SamAccountName + " successfully added to VPN group: " + $ADGroup)
        }
        else {
            $ErrorFile.WriteLine("AddToVPN" + "," + $SamAccountName + "," + $VPNGroupError + "," + $ADGroup)
            Write-Warning $VPNGroupError
            $Error.Clear()
        }
    }
```

My cells in my csv file look similar to this:

```
Business Partner Employee - AD Group Membership
Group1;Group2
```

At one point, I had it working where it added both of the AD groups. When I ran it again on a test account, the verbose states both groups were successfully added, but it actually only adds the first one.

```
VERBOSE: JDoe1 successfully added to VPN group: Group1
VERBOSE: JDoe1 successfully added to VPN group: Group2
```

If I format the cell with the AD groups like this:

```
Group1;Group2;
```

It adds both groups, but the verbose shows an additional blank group has been added (when in reality, it hasn't).

```
VERBOSE: JDoe1 successfully added to VPN group: Group1
VERBOSE: JDoe1 successfully added to VPN group: Group2
VERBOSE: JDoe1 successfully added to VPN group:
```

Any ideas why it won't add the second AD group without the ';' or how I can remove the blank addition if I add the ';'?

Comment: How do you parse the csv file? Are you using the inbuilt Features or reading it line by line? One possible answer could be the `\r` and `\n` problem. Without `;`, group name has a trailing line break and fails. With `;` the 3rd group addition fails because it tries to add a group with a break as name.

Comment: I'm using a foreach loop to read the file: foreach ($Line in $File). It's reading in each line and setting the other variables appropriately, so I assume it's doing the same here when it creates the $VPNGroups variable.

Comment: Have a look at [Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) and give it a try.

Comment: Instead of `-WarningVariable` can you try `-ErrorVariable`?